# Finding the missing list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list `I` arranged in order of increasing `j`. I want to find the missing `j` values. (To clarify, for `[[8, 1]]`, `i=8,j=1`). The desired output is attached.

```
I=[[[8, 1]],
 [[1, 2]],
 [[0, 3]],
 [[15, 7]],
 [[7, 8]],
 [[2, 9], [8, 9]],
 [[9, 10]]]
```

The desired output is:

```
Missing=[4,5,6]
```

How can I produce the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate a set of numbers that *do* appear in the list, and then identify the missing numbers by determining whether or not they appear in the set:

```py
minimum = I[0][0][1]
maximum = I[-1][0][1]
included_numbers = {entry for sublist in I for _, entry in sublist}
[i for i in range(minimum, maximum) if i not in included_numbers]
```

This outputs:

```py
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to use sets. One set with the expected `j` values and one with the actual values. Then you can subtract the sets and print the missing ones.

```
items = [[[8, 1]],
         [[1, 2]],
         [[0, 3]],
         [[15, 7]],
         [[7, 8]],
         [[2, 9], [8, 9]],
         [[9, 10]]]

expected = set(range(1, 11))
actual = set([item[0][1] for item in items])
print(expected - actual)
```

If you need the output as a list, simply cast to a list like so:

```
missing = list(expected - actual)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the value starts at 1, the following code can solve the problem"

```
def find_missing(I):
  current_max = 1
  missing = []
  for row in I:
    for i,j in row:
      if j > current_max:
        missing.extend(list(range(current_max,j)))
      current_max = j+1
  return missing
```